# Does switching boot modes (UEFI/Legacy BIOS) run the risk of bricking a PC/Laptop?

Tags: bios

Is it generally safe to switch boot modes (From UEFI to Legacy BIOS or vice versa) or is there a high chance that it will brick your PC/laptop? I have come across several posts online lately of this happening; see below. Simple changes such as changing the boot mode and changing the boot order can cause bricking??

Why does this kind of thing happen and how can it be prevented?

1. He swapped the boot mode to UEFI and afterwards he can't get into BIOS or boot mode at all. https://linustechtips.com/topic/1036676-bricked-bios-by-switching-to-uefi-mode/
2. He changed the boot mode to Legacy and then can't get it to boot into BIOS or back to UEFI mode. https://www.reddit.com/r/MSILaptops/comments/dhrxfj/how_to_boot_into_bios_or_uefi/
3. Laptop bricked simply because of changing boot order in order to boot a new Linux UEFI Installation. https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/2mzv27/after_changing_some_settings_on_the_bios_the/
4. Changing boot mode again bricks the laptop. https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Another-XPS-15-9550-bricked-after-BIOS-change-from-UEFI-to/td-p/7319627
5. Changing boot mode bricks his machine. https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/problem-booting-after-changing-uefi-bios-to-legacy-bios.1597914/

Comment: To brick: to be totally & utterly beyond salvage, like a brick, a doorstop. To be misconfigured but recoverable to full operation by merely wiping & starting afresh is not bricked. It is really, really difficult to brick a computer running from a HD/SSD.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing, that is loaded when control changes from the device Firmware to the installed OS image is the bootloader. This can be the Windows bootmanager, GRUB legacy, GRUB2, the BSD boot loader, whatever.

Now this boot loader hast to interact with the Firmware to find the next things to load - and of course this is different if interacting with an UEFI environment than when interacting with a legacy BIOS environment.

So the bootloader must know the environment it is in and be at least configured for it (if not a different version is used for different environments). This implies, that changing the boot environment might easily break the bootloader's ability to load the next components, rendering the boot process unusable.